# Barycentric triangulation and Eulers Formula

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Given a triangulated surface, I'm trying to show that after a barycentric subdivision of all the triangles that Euler's formula is equivalent for both triangulations. So given an initial V, F, and E, I need to show that after a barycentric subdivision which gives us the new values: V', E', and F' that:

V-E+F=V'-E'+F'

I have tried to look at the simplest case where there is only one triangle, and find formulas for E,F and V, and then attempt a proof by induction, but this was incredibly difficult and tedious. Does anyone have any advice about how I should proceed with this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$V' = V + E + F$$
because you add one vertex at the barycenter of each edge, and one vertex at the barycenter of each face.

$$E' = 2E + 6F$$
because you subdivide each edge into two edges meeting at the barycenter, and you subdivide each face using $6$ edges, connecting the barycenter of that face to the three vertices and to the barycenters of the three edges.

$$F' = 6F$$
because you subdivide each face into 6 faces.

$$V' - E' + F' = (V+E+F) - (2E+6F) + 6F = V-E+F
$$

Comment: So this works if you have one triangle, but what if you have a n triangles making up the surface? Wouldn't that change the values for V',E' and F'? Or am I not seeing something?

Comment: Look at the definition of barycentric subdivision. Each individual simplex is subdivided in the exact method that I have described. If you have $V=n$ triangles, each individual one of those triangles is subdivided into $6$ triangles, and therefore you have $V'=6n=6V$ triangles after the subdivision.